# How to use incollection, when author and editor are the same and I'm using more than one chapter?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a reference in bibtex, where the author of a chapter is the same as the editor. On top of that, I'm citing more than one chapter. What is the proper/right way to do the citing? For now, I'm using @BOOK, but I realize that would not be the right way.

```
@BOOK{X,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    publisher = {publisher},
    year = {1234},
}
```

But I want something like

```
@INCOLLECTION{X,
    author = {author},
    editor = {author},
    title = {title},
    booktitle = {booktitle},
    publisher = {publisher},
    year = {1234}
}
```

which is probably not the best way since there are more chapters I am citing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is an anthology i.e. different authors and that you are not using Biblatex:

```
@INCOLLECTION{X-a,
    author = {author},
    title = {article title},
    pages = {123--234},
    crossref = {X},
}
@INCOLLECTION{X-b,
    author = {author, another},
    title = {another title},
    pages = {12--34},
    crossref = {X},
}
@BOOK{X,
    author = {author},
    editor = {author},
    title = {title},
    booktitle = {booktitle},
    publisher = {publisher},
    address = {place},
    year = {1234},
}
```

`@BOOK` ***must be later in the `.bib` file*** than the entries which reference it.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it's bibtex. It's more like a collection (even the editor says collection on his website). I want to cite the first two chapter, which have both their own title and are written by the editor of this collection. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough. For reference what I am using: [link](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/HandbookProofTheory/index.html)

Comment: @DonJoe Thanks. Yes, so I'd do it this way using BibTeX. (I use Biblatex/Biber now mostly, but I'd still use more-or-less the same approach.) Just make sure that the entry for the main book comes after all the entries for the chapters in the `.bib` file.